# Teradata : String contains untranslatable character

Tags: teradata

in teradata i have two tables . Both of them display data correctly and fine

```
select * from table1;
select * from table2;
```

---

however the following query throws an error 
`string contains untranslatable character`

```
insert into table1
(varone)
select varone from table2
;
```

why could that happen ? both tables are in teradata which means they do not have any bad characters otherwise they would not be in teradata in the first place

Comment: can you show us the create table statements for both tables .. kind of hard to guess like this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check charset of the table, i think it are differ.

```
show table table1
show table table2
```

If varone contains unicode chars you can get such error... or check fields type